# How to make STD show on the sides of the mean on a forestplot or any other package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

It doesn't matter the package, I would like to produce a plot similar to this one:

[image]

Instead of HR, I want to use the standard mean difference(SMD), however, I want to plot the mean and standard deviation around it, NOT the effect size and its variation.

My dataframe has multiple studies, each study has the following column: study(study author), year(publication year), mc(mean control), sm(STD control), m(sample size control), mp(mean patients), sm(STD patients), m(sample size patients), yi(effect size), vi(variation of effect size).

This is my data sample:

```
A tibble: 14 × 8
   study  year     c      p    mc    mp    sc    sp
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2000  34.6   5       54  44.7   5.6     6
 2     2  2001  52.4  15       26  76.9  23       8
 3     3  2002  42.4   9.94    69  72.1  24.7     9
 4     4  2003  90.2  35.2      4  53.5   1       1
 5     5  2004  40.9   8.1     40  77    29.7     8
 6     6  2005  44.8   8.8     38  84.5  26.2     8
 7     7  2006  40.7  13.1     88  76    31.8     5
 8     8  2007  55.4  33.6      7  35.2  18.8     3
 9     9  2008 372.  104.      74 524.  221       9
```

My code output is not as nearly as good as in the example:

```
    library(forestplot)
labeltext <- paste(effect_p$study, effect_p$year)

# Create a color palette with transparency
colors_with_alpha <- fpColors(c(alpha("blue", 0.8), alpha("red", 0.8)))

# Create a forest plot with increased space between studies labels
forestplot(
  labeltext = labeltext,
  mean = cbind(effect_p$mc, effect_p$mp),
  lower = cbind(effect_p$sc, effect_p$sp),
  upper = cbind(effect_p$sc, effect_p$sp),
  boxsize = 0.5,
  col = fpColors(box = c("blue", "red")),
  title = "",
  xlab = "Mean",
  txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontsize = 10, col = "black", lineheight = 0.1)),  # Set lineheight to increase space
  colgap = unit(4, "mm"),  # Adjust the space between labels
  lwd.ci = 20,
  grid = FALSE,  # Set grid to FALSE to remove the vertical axis line
  hrzl_lines = NULL,  # Add horizontal lines
  # is.summary = c(TRUE, rep(FALSE)),
  fn.ci_norm = fpDrawNormalCI,
  fn.ci_sum = fpDrawDiamondCI,  # Use fpDrawDiamondCI for summary
  lwd.zero = 0,
  clip = c(0, 500),
  vertices = TRUE,
  lty.ci = 1,  # Set to 1 or 2 based on your preference
  line.margin = NULL,  # No need to adjust line.margin in this case
  mar = unit(rep(5, times = 4), "mm")
)
```

I wanted to update my second trial using ggplt2, which is almost what I wanted, but I'm getting three mean points instead of one.
This is the figure:
[image]

This is the code:

```
# Create a long-format data frame
bb_long <- bb %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -c(study, year)) %>%
  separate(variable, into = c("measure", "group"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value)),
         group = ifelse(measure %in% c("mp", "sp", "p"), "Non", "Yes"))

# Calculate standard deviation separately for each group
bb_long <- bb_long %>%
  group_by(study, group) %>%
  mutate(sd = sd(value))

# Create a forest plot using ggplot2
ggplot(platelets_long, aes(x = value, y = study, color = group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  geom_errorbarh(
    aes(xmin = value - sd, xmax = value + sd),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6),
    height = 0.2
  ) +
  labs(x = "Mean", y = "Study", color = "Group") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  ggtitle("Forest Plot of Studies")
```

Percent table:

```
A tibble: 14 × 8
   study  year     c      p    mc     mp     sc    sp
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2000  34.6   5      100   82.8  10.4  11.1 
 2     2  2001  52.4  15      100  296.   88.5  30.8 
 3     3  2002  42.4   9.94   100  104.   35.8  13.0 
 4     4  2003  90.2  35.2    100 1338.   25    25   
 5     5  2004  40.9   8.1    100  192.   74.2  20   
 6     6  2005  44.8   8.8    100  222.   68.9  21.1 
 7     7  2006  40.7  13.1    100   86.4  36.1   5.68
 8     8  2007  55.4  33.6    100  503.  269.   42.9 
 9     9  2008 372.  104.     100  709.  299.   12.2 
10    10  2009  54.7  21.5    100   50.9  23.3   4.58
11    11  2010  46.8   9.8    100  134.   41.0  14.8 
12    12  2011  14.0   2.76   100   12.6   6.29  7.93
13    13  2012  36.2   8.38   100   60.5  19.0   6.67
14    14  2013  36.8  15.2    100  105    49.8  21.4
```

Comment: Hi Adam. No-one is going to be able to provide a verified working answer unless you include enough data in your question to allow us to generate a plot. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `dput(effect_p)`, or create a similarly structured dataset if you do not wish to share your real data. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, I just updated my post! I honestly thought any randomized data set could fit, I wanted to make it easy, that's why I did not add sample of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem appears to be that you are using mutate instead of summarize to get the standard deviations. You therefore have multiple values for each group in each study. Using the sample data you provided as `bb`, we can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bb %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(study, year)) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(name %in% c("mp", "sp", "p"), "Non", "Yes"),
         study = factor(study),
         value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>%
  summarize(sd = sd(value), value = mean(value), .by = c(study, group)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = study, color = group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbarh(
    aes(xmin = value - sd, xmax = value + sd),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6),
    height = 0.4, linewidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  labs(x = "Mean", y = "Study", color = "Group") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Forest Plot of Studies")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron ! I immensely appreciate that you took the time to read my post and identified the wrong code, you are way ahead of me, I'm still learning at very low speed.

Comment: I've noticed something wrong with the output, but I don't know how to explain it, I added a table for the same values but I converted the mc, mp, sc and sp values into a percentage for each study based on mc value of that study, so all mc values are 100 for each, how to align and keep all mc values in one vertical line but mp values are placed based on their values related to mc? ie,to make the mc values fixed in plot (since all of them are 100, they should make one nice vertical line, while the mp is flexible and mostly will be on the right side of the mc.

Comment: I mean if we moved the vertical line from zero to 100, then all the mc values will fall into that line, while the mp values will falls around them.